# Using react-cookie in a util file

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-universal

I am using react-cookie v2 in my react/redux app. To set a cookie you need to wrap the component in a HOC `withCookies(component)`, then you can use `this.props.cookies.set('first_cookie', someCookie);` to set a cookie.

However, i would like to set my cookies in a util file that all my components can use to set cookies. For example.

```
storageUtil.js
export const setToCookies = (key, value, options) => {
    cookies.set(key, value, options);
};
```

This util file cannot be wrapped with `withCookies` and therefore doesnt have the cookies directly. 
I could pass in the cookies instance from the using component (`setToCookies(cookiesInstance, key, value, options)`), but I would rather import a cookie instance in the util file if possible somehow.

This has to be a very common usecase (to handle cookies in a util file), i just cannot figure out the best approach for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I will write the two methods i found to work when searching for a generic solution. If a better solution is provided i will change accepted answer.

**Solution 1:**

```
withCustomCookies.js

import React from 'react';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';

export function withCustomCookies(Component) {

    return (props) => {
        // CookieComponent needs a capital letter bc of JSX
        let ExtendedCookieComponent = withCookies(withEncapsulatedCookies(Component));

        return (
            <ExtendedCookieComponent
                {...props} />
        );
    };
}

export function withEncapsulatedCookies(Component) {

    return (props) => {
        // Only expose our own cookies methods defined in this scope
        const {
            // Dont expose cookies in using component
            cookies, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
            ...cleanedProps
        } = props;

        function getFromCookies(key) {
            // Stuff to always do when getting a cookie
            return cookies.get(key);
        }

        function setToCookies(key, value, options) {
            // Stuff to always do when setting a cookie
            cookies.set(key, value, options);
        }

        return (
            <Component
                getFromCookies={getFromCookies}
                setToCookies={setToCookies}
                {...cleanedProps} /> // All Props except for cookies
        );
    };
}
```

Used as:

1. import and wrap `export default withCustomCookies(Component);`
2. Use like this inside component `this.props.getFromCookies(COOKIE_NAME);`

**Solution 2:**

Use a regular cookieUtils file and pass in the cookies:

```
cookieUtils.js
export const setToCookies = (cookies, key, value, options) => {
   // Stuff to always do when setting a cookie
   cookies.setCookie(key, value, options);
};
```

Use as:

1. Import setToCookies in your component and use withCookies on your Component (`withCookies(NameOfComponent)`).
2. Use the method in component as `setToCookies(this.props.cookies, key, value, options);`